# why i cannot get the correct file permission at android application?

Tags: android, embedded-linux, android-sdcard, mount

I'm porting the new Android4.2 to our own hardware.
we use vold to mount a partition of mmc to /mnt/sdcard and close the multi-user function.
in the terminal we can found the sdcard with 0777 permission.
but when we use android app such as "es file manager" to browse the /mnt/sdcard , it toasts "no sdcard mounted"

then , i try to test it , and write a little program . when i try to access the file, it return the permission 0000 , which is defined by init.rc before we mounted the partition.

in vold.fstab

```
dev_mount sdcard /mnt/sdcard 1 /devices/platform/ns115-sdmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc1
```

in init.xxx.rc

```
   export EXTERNAL_STORAGE /mnt/sdcard                                                             
   mkdir /mnt/sdcard 0000 system system
   symlink /mnt/sdcard /sdcard
```

in vold , we mount the mmc disk at /mnt/sdcard with fstype vfat and give permission 0777 , and the uid=system gid=sdcard_rw

look at the mounts:

```
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
/dev/root / ext3 rw,relatime,errors=continue,barrier=0,data=writeback 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,mode=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/secure tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=700 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
/dev/block/vold/179:1 /mnt/sdcard vfat   rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0000,dmask=0000,allow_ut0
/dev/block/vold/179:1 /mnt/secure/asec vfat    rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0000,dmask=0000,al0
tmpfs /mnt/sdcard/.android_secure tmpfs ro,relatime,size=0k,mode=000 0 0
```

i try these test:

1. use app to access the /mnt/sdcard    failed with permission denied 0000
2. use native service do the same test  success with 0777
3. in terminal check the /mnt/sdcard    success with 0777

so i'm wondering whether it has relation with app's sign ?

Comment: Please post logcat and dmesg logs.

Comment: How are you testing access in the terminal?  And how are you getting a unix file permission code out of an application error message in the denied case?  Have you looked into possible enforcement of the read sdcard permission in android 4.x?

Comment: 1. i use minicom to connect the device with root user.
2. i use lstat to get s_mode flag. and when i invoke opendir , it returns errno 13(EACCES)
3. the only difference between 4.1 and 4.2 is "multiple user" function,and i have tried mount the sdcard in init process by using fuse and sdcard service,and it works. all the apps can see the sdcard.
but i still don't know why apps forked by zygote can't see the sdcard mounted by vold which is also a root user process.

Comment: It may well have to do with the per-user sdcard thing in 4.2

Comment: maybe, do you know where the implementation is?

Comment: I have a simialr problem with pandaboard. Android can't detect any external storage.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a correct init.rc file which must be in android4.2, if your init.rc in andrdroid4.1,you can add this:
 # mount shared so changes propagate into child namespaces
    mount rootfs rootfs / shared rec 
    mount tmpfs tmpfs /mnt/secure private rec

# Create private mountpoint so we can MS_MOVE from staging
    mount tmpfs tmpfs /mnt/secure mode=0700,uid=0,gid=0